# I don't understand why the variable P wont change to 72025 before begining the next loop

Tags: autohotkey

This is a question about autohotkey So this script is supposed to create a new folder with the name, then download a series of videos, then move on to the next series of videos and download them. This can do one series of videos, but then it tries to put everything in the same folder ie the variable P won't increment from 72024 to 72025 despite the X := ++P argument in the outer loop. What am I messing up? There are 15 videos to a set I have this broken into 3 loops so that I can insert a %delay% of 30 minutes or so to give them time to download and not hammer on the gomtv site too much. This is by far the most complicated script I've ever tried to put together so any constructive criticism is welcome.

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
#Warn  ; Recommended for catching common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
G = 1
H = 1
P = 72024
FolderName = 2013_WCS_KR_Season_1_Code_S_Ro32_Group_A_%P%
FileName = %FolderName%_Set
W = http://www.gomtv.net/2013wcs1/vod/%P%
URL = http://www.gomtv.net/2013wcs1/vod/%P%/?set=
NumberSets = 15 
wTitle = vlcrip
Q = .mp4
Delay = 0

Loop, 2
{ 
Sleep 3000
WinActivate vlcrip
Send {Lshift down}
Sleep 100
Send {F10} 
Sleep 100
Send {Lshift up}
Sleep 100
Send w
Sleep 100
Send w
Sleep 100
Send {Enter}
Sleep 100
Send {Enter}
Sleep 100
Send %FolderName%
Send {Enter}
Sleep 100
Send {Lshift down}
Sleep 100
Send {F10} 
Sleep 100
Send {Lshift up}
Sleep 100
Send e
Sleep 100
WinActivate %FolderName%



Loop, 1
{
sleep 100
Send {Lshift down}
Sleep 100
Send {F10} 
Sleep 100
Send {Lshift up}
Sleep 100
Send w
Send {Enter}
sleep 100
send livestreamer %URL%%H% best -o %FileName%_%H%%Q%
sleep 100
T := ++H
sleep 100
Send {Enter}
Sleep 200
WinActivate %FolderName%
Sleep 200
}

sleep %Delay%

Loop, 1
{
sleep 100
Send {Lshift down}
Sleep 100
Send {F10} 
Sleep 100
Send {Lshift up}
Sleep 100
Send w
Send {Enter}
sleep 100
send livestreamer %URL%%H% best -o %FileName%_%H%%Q%
sleep 100
T := ++H
sleep 100
Send {Enter}
Sleep 200
WinActivate %FolderName%
Sleep 200
}

sleep %Delay%

Loop, 1
{
sleep 100
Send {Lshift down}
Sleep 100
Send {F10} 
Sleep 100
Send {Lshift up}
Sleep 100
Send w
Send {Enter}
sleep 100
send livestreamer %URL%%H% best -o %FileName%_%H%%Q%
sleep 100
T := ++H
sleep 100
Send {Enter}
Sleep 200
WinActivate %FolderName%
Sleep 200
}
X := ++P
Send {Lcontrol down}
Sleep 100
Send {space} 
Sleep 100
Send {Lcontrol up}
Sleep 100
WinActivate vlcrip
Sleep 100
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put-move the commands related to P in to the loop.

```
Loop, 2
{ 
FolderName = 2013_WCS_KR_Season_1_Code_S_Ro32_Group_A_%P%
FileName = %FolderName%_Set
W = http://www.gomtv.net/2013wcs1/vod/%P%
URL = http://www.gomtv.net/2013wcs1/vod/%P%/?set=
...
```

Then it should work.